# Add ID to jsp button

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, button

I have buttons as below:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${openOrders}">

    <tr>             
        <td><input name="getOrder" type="submit" value="- Coffee Order ${item.id}"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>             
        <td><input name="getOrder" type="submit" value="- Coffee Order ${item.id}"/></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I would like to add an `ID` field to this button so in my `servlet` I can retrieve this id. Also how would I test for which button was pressed if the value is dynamic?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

In response to the comment below:

Do you mean something like this?

```
<form>
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${openOrders}">
        <tr>             
            <td><input name="getOrder" type="submit" value="- Coffee Order ${item.id}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
     <input type="hidden" name="getOrderID" value="${item.id}">     
</form>
```

Because I think if I do it like this, the hidden field will always contain the value of the last item?

Comment: If I'm understanding the question correctly, you would need to add in a hidden field, with a value of ${item.id}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood your requirement correctly, you could have forms for each row. So that when ever user click the button you will only have `getOrder` and hidden field `getOrderId` for each form. So you can use get parameter to get the value as you like.

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${openOrders}">
 <form>  
    <tr>             
      <td>
          <input name="getOrder" type="submit" value="- Coffee Order ${item.id}"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="getOrderID" value="${item.id}">     
      </td>
    </tr>
  </form> 
</c:forEach>
```